# How Tor's fingerprint is calculated?

Tags: configuration, directory

according to Tor's specifications, the fingerprint is

> A fingerprint (a HASH_LEN-byte of asn1 encoded public key, encoded in
>   hex, with a single space after every 4 characters) for this router's
>   identity key. A descriptor is considered invalid (and MUST be
>   rejected) if the fingerprint line does not match the public key.

But I can't manage to recalculate it.

If I correctly understand, the fingerprint is 20 bytes of HEX value of the 'authority_signing_key', right ?

Comment: Have a look at the following thread: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6454/how-is-the-identity-encoded-to-display-the-fingerprint?rq=1

Comment: Failing that, what method are you trying to use to calculate it? Can you show us your workings?

Answer (score 1):

Fingerprint is the SHA1 digest of Base64 decoded public key.
For example, if RSA_PUB is the RSA public key of the authority_certificate
than to calculate the Fingerprint:

```
> echo RSA_PUB | base64 -d | openssl sha1
```

Thanks Richard Horrocks, reminded me on Base64.